# Incorrect truncation of a series expansion

Tags: series-expansion

What is wrong here?

```
fExp = f0 + f1 Sqrt[s] + f2 s + O[s]^(3/2);
{s fExp + O[s]^(3/2),s f + O[s]^(3/2)/.f->fExp}
```

Returns

```
{SeriesData[s, 0, {f0}, 2, 3, 2], SeriesData[s, 0, {}, 3, 3, 2]}
```

or `f0 s+O(s^(3/2))` and `O(s^(3/2))}` in a traditional form.
The latter result is incorrect.

Comment: In version 12.1 the second result is `SeriesData[s, 0, {f0, f1}, 2, 4, 2]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau your result is better but still not the answer I would expect. I'm on version 11.0 currently. So this could be a bug in that older version?

Comment: (1) 11.0 shows the empty series. 11.1 has three terms, and that persists until version 12.1.

Comment: (2) Placing a `SeriesData` inside another that has the same variable is a recipe for trouble. Internal operations to unwind this may raise an order term to the nearest larger integer, for example.

Comment: (3) In this example, what we have after the replacement is `SeriesData[s, 0, {SeriesData[s, 0, {f0, f1, f2}, 0, 3, 2]}, 2, 3, 2]`. The `Series` code attempts to resolve this by evaluating `Series[SeriesData[s, 0, {f0, f1, f2}, 2, 5, 2], {s, 0, 1}]`. At this point it is clear there will be a second term in the result. One can argue that this is wrong, but then, see item (2) above.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I would think that the composition of two series should be a well-defined operation but I have not thought this through. Btw If I replace `s->s^2` then all formulas are in agreement (this is what I did in my actual code).

Comment: I do not recommend composing by substituting a `SeriesData` object into a coefficient of a different `SeriesData` object. `ComposeSeries` might be more along the lines of what you need, maybe.